# Lua5.2: Torch tutorial gives an __index based Stack Overflow

Tags: lua, stack-overflow, torch, metatable

I have been wanting to get into `torch` and started with this [tutorial](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb). However I ran into a stack overflow when running the code specifically with the `setmetatable` function. I believe that this is happening because of the large 50000 image input file but I might be wrong. I have tried editing the `luaconf.h` file to try to fix it to no avail. Other than that I am running `torch` with `Lua 5.2` and without `iTorch` as I had trouble setting it up.

Here is the error:

```
/home/student/torch/install/bin/lua: C stack overflow
stack traceback:
[C]: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
...
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:56: in function '__index'
Documents/TorchImageRecognition.lua:66: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
...dent/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

Otherwise my code should be the same as in the tutorial from **1. Load and normalize the data** to **4. Train the neural network**

Here's my code, sorry for not initially having it.

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'
require 'paths'

if (not paths.filep("cifar10torchsmall.zip")) then
    os.execute('wget -c https://s3.amazonaws.com/torch7/data/cifar10torchsmall.zip')
    os.execute('unzip cifar10torchsmall.zip')
end
trainset = torch.load('cifar10-train.t7')
testset = torch.load('cifar10-test.t7')
classes = {'airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'}

print(trainset)
print(#trainset.data)

--itorch.image(trainset.data[100])
--print(classes[trainset.label[100]])
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- This code is from the previous parts of the tutorial
--net = nn.Sequential() 
--net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 6, 5, 5))
--neecognitiont:add(nn.ReLU())
--net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
--net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(6, 16, 5, 5))
--net:add(nn.ReLU())
--net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
--net:add(nn.View(16*5*5))
--net:add(nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120))
--net:add(nn.ReLU())
--net:add(nn.Linear(120, 84))
--net:add(nn.ReLU())
--net:add(nn.Linear(84, 10))
--net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())

--print('Lenet5\n' .. net:__tostring())

--input = torch.rand(1, 32, 32)
--output = net:forward(input)
--print(output)
--net:zeroGradParameters()
--gradInput = net:backward(input, torch.rand(10))
--print(#gradInput)

--criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()
--criterion:forward(output, 3)
--gradients = criterion:backward(output,  3)

--gradInput = net:backward(input, gradients)

--m= nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 3, 2, 2)
--print(m.weight)
--print(m.bias)
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

setmetatable(trainset, {__index = function(t, i)
        return {t.data[i], t.lable[i]}
end})
trainset.data = trainset.data:double()

function trainset:size()
    return self.data:size(1)
end

print(trainset:size())

print(trainset[33])

redChannel = trainset.data[{ {}, {1}, {}, {} }]
print(#redChannel)

mean = {}
stdv = {}
for i=1,3 do
    mean[i] = trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {} }]:mean()
    print('Channel ' .. i .. ', Mean: ' .. mean[i])
    trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {} }]:add(-mean[i])

    stdv[i] = trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {} }]:std()
    print('Channel ' .. i .. ', Standard Deviation: ' .. stdv[i])
    trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {} }]:div(stdv[i])
end

net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3, 6, 5, 5))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(6, 16, 5, 5))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
net:add(nn.View(16*5*5))
net:add(nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.Linear(120, 84))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.Linear(84, 10))
net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())

criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()

trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(net, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.001
trainer.maxIteration = 5
trainer:train(trainset)
```

Comment: Post your code here, we cannot guess what is line 56 in there

Comment: Blind guess is that `t.data` or `t.label` is nil in `__index` around `setmetatable` call, so it recurses forever

Comment: Or he sets something which calls __newindex, which in turn indexes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in setmetatable, t.lable instead of t.label